# App build gives error

Tags: android, google-analytics-firebase

In my android app , I need to use google Analytics and below is my build.gradle file

```
    dependencies {
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile files('libs/android-mads-4.5.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    //compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

but still I get the following error

> Error:(8, 45) error: package com.google.analytics.tracking.android
>   does not exist

Answer (score 0):

please go through this [link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/).

you haven't add google services in dependency.

```
com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0
```

Comment: Hi, I suppose this needs to be added to project level build file , i have added it   
    
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

Comment: yes it is in classpath only check for other changes in link I sent.

Comment: I already did.... Mine is same as described in your and below answer's link. but still this problem is there.     and sometimes after build i get this error too Error:Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command$1.class

Answer (score 0):

Add following dependency to project level build.gradle file

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Add the plugin to bottom of your app level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Now you should add dependency for Google Play Services
Inside app level build.gradle, add following code

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#set-up-your-project